# How to compare strings in Bash script

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have one strings like "9999991385" now I want to match first 4 digits from one file if it's match or not ??

Comment: Please try to clarify your question, maybe by providing sample input and output.

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash example

You can yank a substring from a bash variable using variable manipulation ${::} like so

```
x="9999991385";
echo ${x:0:4}; # prints 9999
```

Although what your doing in or getting from 'one file' isn't exactly clear to me, you can compare strings like so:

```
x="9999991385";
[[ "${x:0:4}" ==  "some string" ]] && some_thing_useful_here;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
num=9999991385
[[ $num =~ ^([O-9]{4}).* ]] && echo match
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```